# After Update Android Studio 3.3 to 3.4 AAPT2 error generated

Tags: android, aapt2

After Update Android Studio 3.3 to 3.4 its getting error.
it's getting an error that is AAPT2 and that provide me one suggested me to like this:

**Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See**

```
gradle.properties
org.gradle.warning.mode=all
```

but still it not working.

error :

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeIntroMakerDebugResources'.
> 8 exceptions were raised by workers:
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.0-5326820-windows Daemon #2: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.0-5326820-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.0-5326820-windows Daemon #1: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.0-5326820-windows Daemon #3: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.0-5326820-windows Daemon #4: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.0-5326820-windows Daemon #5: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.0-5326820-windows Daemon #6: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.0-5326820-windows Daemon #7: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 23s
```

this is Build.gradle file :

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    // The Fabric Gradle plugin uses an open ended version to react
    // quickly to Android tooling updates
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
}
 }

plugins {
id "com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin" version "0.12.1"
 }

   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
 //Put Fabric plugin after Android plugin
 apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
  apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'

repositories {
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
android {
signingConfigs {
    config {
        keyAlias 'maker_key'
        keyPassword '!23342'
        storeFile 
       file('E:/axita.savani/Android_Project/AppCred/maker_key.jks')
        storePassword '!23342'
    }
}
compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 28
       vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    multiDexEnabled true
    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a"
    }
}
buildTypes {
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android- 
     optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        zipAlignEnabled true
        shrinkResources false
        externalNativeBuild { ndkBuild { cFlags '-DDEBUG' } }
    }
    release {
        debuggable false
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android- 
     optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        zipAlignEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        externalNativeBuild { ndkBuild { cFlags '-DRELEASE' } }
    }
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        res.srcDirs =
                [
                        'src/main/res/layouts/activities',
                        'src/main/res/layouts/fragments',
                        'src/main/res/layouts/background',
                        'src/main/res/layouts/camera',
                        'src/main/res/layouts/sticker',
                        'src/main/res/layouts/text',
                        'src/main/res/layouts/editor',
                        'src/main/res/layouts/commom',
                        'src/main/res/layouts/other',
                        'src/main/res/layouts/videotrimmer',
                        'src/main/res/layouts/obgallarylib',
                        'src/main/res/layouts/template',
                        'src/main/res/layouts/eraser',
                        'src/main/res/layouts/user_guide',
                        'src/main/res/layouts/my_art',
                        'src/main/res/layouts/audio',
                        'src/main/res/layouts/video',

                        'src/main/res/layouts-land/activities',
                        'src/main/res/layouts-land/fragments',
                        'src/main/res/layouts-land/background',
                        'src/main/res/layouts-land/camera',
                        'src/main/res/layouts-land/sticker',
                        'src/main/res/layouts-land/text',
                        'src/main/res/layouts-land/editor',
                        'src/main/res/layouts-land/commom',
                        'src/main/res/layouts-land/other',
                        'src/main/res/layouts-land/my_art',

                        'src/main/res/layouts',
                        'src/main/res/layouts-land',
                        'src/main/res'
                ]
    }
}

  android {
    aaptOptions {
        ignoreAssetsPattern "!*ffprobe"
    }
    dexOptions {
        jumboMode true
    }
    lintOptions {
        disable 'GoogleAppIndexingWarning'
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in 
 release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }
}

def flavorName = 'Maker'
// todo change in flavorname which app is used

externalNativeBuild {
    ndkBuild {
        path "src/${flavorName}/jni/Android.mk"
    }
}

flavorDimensions "default"

product flavors {

    // ONE SIGNAL IDs
        Maker {
        applicationId "com.example.maker"

        versionCode 9
        versionName "9.0"
        flavorDimensions "default"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        setProperty("archivesBaseName", 
    "Business_$versionName.$versionCode")
    }


}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility 1.8
    targetCompatibility 1.8
}
}

  dependencies {
/*TODO one Signal*/
implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.10.6'

implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
 //    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
//implementation 'com.android.support:palette-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'

 //    implementation 'com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.1'
implementation 'com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.2'

//    implementation 'com.kbeanie:multipicker:1.1.31@aar'
   //    implementation project(path: ':multipicker')

    /*database Dislay From chorome used this */
implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.5.0'

implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'

/* Pinch zoom image */
//implementation 'com.davemorrissey.labs:subsampling-scale-image- 
 view:3.6.0'

implementation 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar'

/*GIF Image View*/
implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.16'

/* YOYO animation*/
implementation 'com.daimajia.easing:library:2.0@aar'
implementation 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:2.3@aar'

implementation 'com.codemybrainsout.rating:ratingdialog:1.0.8'

/* FCM */
//    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2'
/* AdMob */
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.2.0'

/* InAppPurchase */
implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:1.2'

/* EU User Consent SDK */
implementation 'com.google.android.ads.consent:consent-library:1.0.7'

//For Crash analytics
implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.7@aar') {
    transitive = true
}

implementation 'com.azeesoft.lib.colorpicker:colorpicker:1.0.9@aar'
implementation 
'com.h6ah4i.android.widget.verticalseekbar:verticalseekbar:0.7.2'


implementation 'nl.bravobit:android-ffmpeg:1.1.5'
implementation 'com.googlecode.mp4parser:isoparser:1.1.22'
/*storage for path */
implementation 'com.snatik:storage:2.1.0'
/*exo player for Audio and Video */
implementation 'com.devbrackets.android:exomedia:4.3.0'

/*Download file From Server */
implementation 'com.mindorks.android:prdownloader:0.5.0'

      /*Ob Volly library*/
implementation 'com.optimumbrew.corelib:networking-volly:8.0.8'
   /*Audio picker library */
implementation 'com.optimumbrew.picker:audiopicker:1.1.17'

/* Optimumbrew Image loader*/
implementation 'com.optimumbrew.obglide:obglide:2.0.2'
/* inhouse ads library*/
implementation 'com.optimumbrew.obinhouseads:obinhouseads:11.0.11'

implementation project(path: ':spacelib')

/*Video Tools*/
implementation project(':video-record')
implementation project(':video-compressor')
implementation project(':video-effect')

implementation 'com.daasuu:ExoPlayerFilter:0.2.3'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.5'
implementation 'com.tbruyelle.rxpermissions2:rxpermissions:0.9.4@aar'

implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'

//exo player note : Don't upgrade of exoplayer vesion
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.9.1'

implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'




}
   //apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' // Use for FCM Push
```

Comment: please post your app and project level gradle.

Comment: There must be an API change in Android Studio Gradle plugin. However I can't found it in release notes. If found, then it is the answer.

Comment: I find the solution on this post answer and works fine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55792956/aapt2-aapt2-3-4-0-5326820-windows-daemon-error

Comment: it is a Bug in aapt2. I opened issue in issuetracker, check it out https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/131883685

Answer (score 0):

Use ./gradlew build --warning-mode all in Android Studio terminal to get more info.

First thing to do is always Invalidate caches + restart.

Comment: Then try 'gradlew build --warning-mode all'. Post errors, we can't help you otherwise

Comment: no, it's not working for me it's getting the same error as above.

Comment: Post your project level build.gradle file. Your current Gradle version is too high, it doesn't support Android yet.

Answer (score 0):

Please change `build script {` into `buildscript {` without space. it will work. Also try to use `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip` in "gradle-wrapper.properties" and sync again

Comment: try to use "distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip" in "gradle-wrapper.properties" and sync again

Comment: in my project I have used this: distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip.

Comment: try to use "4.10.1-all" and sync