# AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.0-5326820-windows Daemon Error

Tags: android

when I update my Android Studio version 3.3.2 to 3.4 It Cause Problem of

> com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2,InternalException: AAPT2
>   aapt2-3.4.0-5326820-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed.

I also create a new Project it build successfully but when i run in device then it gives error

My distributionUrl is `https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip`

My Gradle Version `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0`

Answer (score 6):

If you have updated the Android studio to 3.4 or using Android Studio 3.4
there is issue with gradle version 
downgrade the gradle version work fine

**Change**

```
  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4'
```

**to**

```
  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
```

Comment: Thank you, you save my day!

Answer (score 0):

From 3.4 onward you need to install the Windows Universal C Runtime (https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/2999226/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows)

Comment: I have Android Studio 4.0 and all my builds fail due to the above error. When I try to install Windows Universal C Runtime, it says it already exists.